# How can I output Unicode symbols in Python 3.0?

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x

I am working on a little euchre project for those of you who are familiar with that. I need suit symbols to identify the cards in my game. Unicode seems to be the best way of doing that.

I am using Eclipse for IDE developers coupled with a pydev module. It's running Python 3.0.

It should just be as simple as:

```
club = u"\u2663".encode('utf-8')
print(club)
```

My output is literally:

```
>>> b'\xe2\x99\xa3'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Python 3.0 doesn't support the ``u""`` syntax (which you shouldn't be using in the first place), so I doubt it's the exact version you have. Most likely it's 3.3.

Answer (score 7):

Don't encode; the `sys.stdout` file stream is opened with your terminal encoding and encodes unicode for you:

```
club = u"\u2663"
print(club)
```

You don't need to use `u''`; python 3 strings are unicode values *by default*.

Demo:

```
>>> club = "\u2663"
>>> print(club)
♣
```

Answer (score 5):

That you shouldn't need to encode.

```
3>> print('\u2663')
♣
```